# Aligning to height/depth maps

Tags: algorithm, optimization, vision

I have 2 2D depth/height maps of equal dimension (256 x 256). Each pixel/cell of the depth map image, contains a float value. There are some pixels that have no information so are set to nan currently. The percentage of non nan cells can vary from ~ 20% to 80%. The depth maps are taken of the same area through point sampling an underlying common surface.

The idea is that the images represent a partial, yet overlapping, sampling of an underlying surface. And I need to align these images to create a combined sampled representation of the surface. If done blindly then the combined images have discontinuities especially in the z dimension (the float value).

What would be a fast method of aligning the 2 images? Translation in the x and y direction should be minimal only a few pixels (~ 0 to 10 pixels). But the float values of one image may need to be adjusted to align the images better. So minimizing the difference between the 2 images is the goal.

Thnx for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are lacunar, one way is the exhaustive computation of a matching score in the window of overlap, ruling out the voids. FFT convolution will not apply. (Workload = overlap area * X-range * Y-range).

If both images differ in noise only, use the SAD matching score. If they also differ by the reference zero, subtract the average height before comparing.

You can achieve some acceleration by using an image pyramid, but you'll need to handle the voids.

Other approach could be to fill in the gaps by some interpolation method that somehow ensures that the interpolated values are compatible between both images.